# R: add a column for the day of value

Tags: r

I have the following code to select days (24h) when both maximum and minimum temperatures have high temperatures (higher than the 90th percentiles of both). The code calculates the length of the individual event and the highest mean temperature recorded during each event.

```
setDT(df)
df[, hotday := +(df$MAX>=(quantile(df$MAX,.90, na.rm = T, type = 6)) & df$MIN>=(quantile(df$MIN,.90, na.rm = T, type = 6)))
          ] [, hw.length := with(rle(hotday), rep(lengths,lengths))
             ] [hotday==0, hw.length:=0][!!hotday, Highest_Mean := max(MEAN) , rleid(hw.length)][]
```

The result of the code looks like this:

```
> head(df)
   YEAR MONTH DAY      Date MEAN  MAX  MIN    D    hotday hw.length Highest_Mean
1: 1991     5  14 5/14/1991 32.2 41.0 23.6 17.4       1         3         34.9
2: 1991     5  15 5/15/1991 34.9 43.3 26.0 17.3       1         3         34.9
3: 1991     5  16 5/16/1991 31.4 39.2 23.6 15.6       1         3         34.9
4: 1994     5  27 5/27/1994 30.7 41.0 23.0 18.0       1         2         30.7
5: 1994     5  28 5/28/1994 30.6 39.4 23.4 16.0       1         2         30.7
```

The first event lived for 3 days and the highest mean was 34.9, but the code does not tell on which day that was recorded (was it on the first, second or third day of the event).
How can I add a column that gives that information along with the maximum length (non-duplicated values, one per each event)? something like this

```
   YEAR MONTH DAY      Date MEAN  MAX  MIN    D    hotday hw.length Highest_Mean  mean.day.max.length
1: 1991     5  14 5/14/1991 32.2 41.0 23.6 17.4       1         3         34.9 
2: 1991     5  15 5/15/1991 34.9 43.3 26.0 17.3       1         3         34.9     2-3
3: 1991     5  16 5/16/1991 31.4 39.2 23.6 15.6       1         3         34.9
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off adding a unique identifying code for each heat wave event and then indexing that,but this solution will work (as long as two events do not have the exact same length and max mean temperature)

```
hottest_day = which(df$MEAN == df$Highest_Mean)
df$mean.day.max.length=""

for(i in hottest_day){
  subset=df[(which(df$hw.length==df$hw.length[i] & df$Highest_Mean==df$Highest_Mean[i])),]
  df$mean.day.max.length[i]=paste0(which(subset$MEAN==df$Highest_Mean[i]),"-",df$hw.length[i])
}
```

Comment: I am glad @Ali. Please tick to accept the answer if it worked :)